# Generics: is there a protocol for InitializableWithString?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to build a generic struct that can be initialized from a String.

Minimal example:

```
struct Example<T> {
    var data: T

    init(fromString string: String) {
        data = T(string)
    }
}
```

This fails, naturally, because we must ensure T can be init() from a String.

I could not find a protocol for this, so I tried to create it:

```
protocol InitializableWithString { init?(_: String) }

struct Example<T: InitializableWithString> { ... }
```

but experimenting with an Int gives:

```
let testVar = Example<Int>(fromString: "12")
```

> error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'InitializableWithString'

But Ints do have a failable initializer that takes a String argument.

```
> let intFromString = Int("12")
intFromString: Int? = 12
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but there is a protocol for types that can be initialized with string *literals*: `StringLiteralConvertible` (`ExpressibleByStringLiteral` in Swift 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK a protocol representing a Type that can be created with a `String` does not exist.

You defined your own which is fine but there are a few errors.

### 1. Naming the parameter

```
protocol InitializableWithString {
    init?(string:String)
}
```

### 2. Making `Int` conform to `InitializableWithString`

The `Int` struct has an initializer used to create an `Int` from a `String`, it is used when we write

```
Int("123")
```

This initializer has the following signature

```
public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

The missing part of this solution is extending `Int` to make it conform to `InitializableWithString` like shown below

```
extension Int: InitializableWithString {
    init?(string: String) {
        self.init(string)
    }
}
```

### 3. Making the `init` of `Example` failable as well

Since the initializer of `InitializableWithString` if failable, you could not be able to build a `T` type. In this case what should the `Example`init` do? The easiest solution is to make it fail so

```
struct Example<T where T: InitializableWithString> {
    var data: T

    init?(string: String) {
        guard let data = T(string: string) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

Now you can write

```
let example = Example<Int>(string: "123")
if let example = example {
    print(example.data)
}
```

### More

Now you can make more types conform to `InitializableWithString` and then using them to build new `Example(s)` values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't explicitly conformed `Int` to your `InitializableWithString` protocol, therefore even though it may implicitly conform, Swift's type-system won't recognise that fact.

You can explicitly conform it through an extension:

```
extension Int : InitializableWithString {}
```

However, we still get the error:

> Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'InitializableWithString'

The problem *now* is that while `Int` can be initialised with a `String`, it is done so [through this initialiser](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Int/#init_radix_), which has two parameters – the `radix:` parameter just happens to have a default value:

```
/// Construct from an ASCII representation in the given `radix`.
///
/// If `text` does not match the regular expression
/// "[+-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+", or the value it denotes in the given `radix`
/// is not representable, the result is `nil`.
public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

Therefore Swift doesn't recognise that `Int` can satisfy the `init?(_: String)` requirement. The solution therefore is to implement an initialiser that does meet this requirement, and just forwards the call to the `init?(_:radix:)` initialiser, using the default `radix` value:

```
extension Int : InitializableWithString {
    init?(_ str: String) {
        self.init(_:radix:)(str) // the (_:radix:) is used in order to disambiguate
    }
}
```

Or to change your protocol to require a `radix:` parameter, if you also want to be able to deal with non-decimal numeric representations:

```
protocol InitializableWithString {
    init?(_: String, radix:Int)
}
```

With this, you don't need to implement an extra initialiser, as `Int` directly satisfies this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's very much appreciated.